# RuntimeError: Lock objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance

Tags: pickle, python-multiprocessing, dask, python-xarray

I'm getting a `ValueError: Lock objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance` when writing a xarray.DataArray to_netcdf(). 
Everything works until writing to disk. But I found a workaround which is to use `dask.config.set(scheduler='single-threaded')`.

- Is everyone supposed to use `dask.config.set(scheduler='single-threaded')` before writing to disk?
- Am I missing something?

I tested two schedulers:

1) `from dask.distributed import Client;  client = Client()`

2) `import dask.multiprocessing; dask.config.set(scheduler=dask.multiprocessing.get)`

python=2.7, xarray=0.10.9, traceback:

```
  File "/home/py_user/miniconda2/envs/v0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xarray/core/dataarray.py", line 1746, in to_netcdf
    return dataset.to_netcdf(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/py_user/miniconda2/envs/v0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py", line 1254, in to_netcdf
    compute=compute)
  File "/home/py_user/miniconda2/envs/v0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py", line 724, in to_netcdf
    unlimited_dims=unlimited_dims, compute=compute)
  File "/home/py_user/miniconda2/envs/v0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py", line 1181, in dump_to_store
    store.sync(compute=compute)
...
  File "/home/py_user/miniconda2/envs/v0/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in __getstate__
    assert_spawning(self)
  File "/home/py_user/miniconda2/envs/v0/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/forking.py", line 52, in assert_spawning
    ' through inheritance' % type(self).__name__
```

Comment: I think the problem mentioned here has since been fixed in Xarray. I suggest updating to a newer version of xarray (and maybe dask). If the problem persists, please open an issue on github: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues

Answer (score -2):

As @jhamman mentioned in the comments.  This may have been fixed in a newer version of Xarray.